# Exercise 1.20 Functional Analysis Book Brezis.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

This is an exercise  from [Functional Analysis,
Sobolev Spaces and PDEs (by H. Brezis)](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf) (Exercise 1.20 (a) on p. 25):

> Let $E =\ell^p$ with $1\leq p<\infty$. Check that the function $\varphi:E\to (-\infty,+\infty]$ defined below is convex, lower semicontinuous, and determine the conjugate function $\varphi^*$ of $\varphi$. For $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots)$ set:
> $$
>  \varphi(x) =\begin{cases}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k|x_k|^2& \text{if }\sum_{k=1}^\infty
> k|x_k|^2<+\infty, \\+\infty &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases} 
>  $$

I want to find conjugate of the function $ \varphi(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \lvert x_{k} \rvert^{2} $.

The definition of *conjugate function* on p. 11 of that book is given below:

**Definition** (Conjugate function). Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $E^\star$ be the dual space of it.
Denote by $\langle \,\cdot\, ,\,\cdot\,\rangle$  the canonical duality map from $E^\star \times E$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\varphi : E \to (−\infty , +\infty ]$ be a function such that $\varphi \not\equiv  +\infty $. We define the *conjugate function* $\varphi^\star : E^\star \to (−\infty , +\infty ]$ to be
$$\varphi^\star (f)= \sup_{x\in E} \left\{\langle f, x\rangle - \varphi(x)\right\}, \quad f\in E^\star. $$

**Remark.**

> (1) $\varphi^\star$ is convex and lower semicontinuous on $E^\star$.

Indeed, for each fixed $x \in  E$,
$f \mapsto \langle f, x\rangle  − \varphi(x)$ is an affine function (and thus convex and continuous). It's well-known that
the supremum of a collection of convex functions (resp. lower semicontinuous functions) is also convex (resp. lower semicontinuous), hence
$\varphi^\star$ is convex and lower semicontinuous.

> (2) The inequality
> $$\langle f,x\rangle \leq \varphi (x)+ \varphi^\star (f) , \quad \forall x\in E, \ \  \forall f\in E^\star$$
> clearly holds, which is called *Young's inequality*.

Comment: Exercise 1.20 brezis

Comment: There is no question here. Can you give a complete question?

Comment: what does "conjugate function" mean here?

Comment: I received this resolution suggestion, but I understood it very well.See the suggestion below

To compute the conjugate function, you may use Riesz representation theorem for the dual of ell^p (that gives you a formula for f(x)) and then complete the square (the sup is a maximum when it is finite).Exercise 1.20 Brezis Book

Comment: You have to give a context for these words to make any sense. Conjugate function of what? This is not a complete question. Help people help you.

Comment: Exercise 1.20 Functional Analysis Book Brezis

Answer (score -2):

Item a)To determine $\varphi^{*}(f)$:
Let $(e_{k})$ be canonical   Schauder   basis   of    $ l^{p} $ and
$ f \in (l^{p})^{'}$. So for $x= (x_{k} )_{k=1}=$  $\sum_{k=1}$ $x_{k}$ $e_{k} $ you have $ f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$ $x_{k}\alpha_{k}$ where $ \alpha_{k} =f(e_{k}) $.

Let's determine $ \varphi^{*}(f)=  \sup_{x \in (\ell^{p})'}\{ f(x) - \varphi(x) \} < \infty $. Thus, given $ x \in \ell^{p} $. Let $ \varphi_{k}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $ \varphi_{k}(x_{k}) =kx_{k}^{2}$ for every $ k \in \mathbb{N} $. Let $ \alpha_{k}$
such that $f_{k} (x) = \alpha_{k} x_{k}$. Thus, we have to
$\varphi_{k}^*(f)= \displaystyle \sup_{x_{k} \in \mathbb{R}} \{ \alpha_{k} x_{k}-kx^{2}_{k} \} 
={\alpha_{k}^{2}}/{4k} $
because the maximum is assumed when $ ( \alpha_{k}x_{k}-kx_{k}^{2})'=0  $,
that is, in $x_{k}= \alpha_{k}/2k $. Soon,
$
\varphi*(f)=  \displaystyle \sup_{x \in (\ell^{p})'}\{ f(x) - \varphi(x) \} 
=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\alpha_{k}^{2}}{4k} 
= \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\rvert\alpha_{k}\rvert^{2}}{4k} 
= \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\rvert f_{k}\rvert^{2}}{k}$

Comment: Does anyone disagree with this solution?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.